# object-pascal moving picture in frame

Tags: image, delphi

Im working on a school project with object-pascal and im tryingto make an fruitmachine. Im trying to make that wheel that turns around and i've gotten this picture: [icons fruitmachine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qGUZI.png)
I've gotten so far that it only shows the first one but im trying to make the picture move up so it shows the others as wel. Is this possible and if so how?

edit: the picture frame is 100*100 pixels. The picture is 100*900 pixels. i want the picture to move that its show first the pixels from 0 to 100, next step 10 to 110, next step 20 to 120, etc.

Code:

```
unit Unit1;

{$mode objfpc}{$H+}

interface

uses
  Classes, SysUtils, FileUtil, Forms, Controls, Graphics, Dialogs, StdCtrls,
  ExtCtrls, Crt;

type

  { TForm1 }

  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    Button10: TButton;
    Button11: TButton;
    Button12: TButton;
    Button13: TButton;
    Button14: TButton;
    Button15: TButton;
    Button16: TButton;
    Button17: TButton;
    Button18: TButton;
    Button2: TButton;
    Button3: TButton;
    Button4: TButton;
    Button5: TButton;
    Button6: TButton;
    Button7: TButton;
    Button8: TButton;
    Button9: TButton;
    Image1: TImage;
    Image2: TImage;
    Image3: TImage;
    Image4: TImage;
    Image5: TImage;
    Image6: TImage;
    Image7: TImage;
    Image8: TImage;
    Image9: TImage;
    Label1: TLabel;
    Label2: TLabel;
    Label3: TLabel;
    Label4: TLabel;
    Label5: TLabel;
    Timer1: TTimer;
    Timer2: TTimer;
    procedure Button18Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button4Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button5Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button6Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button7Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button8Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button9Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button10Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button11click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button12click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button13click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button14click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button15click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button16click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button17click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Timer1StopTimer(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Timer2Timer(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { private declarations }
  public
    { public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;
  x1, x2, x3, x4, money: double;
  s1, s2, s3, s4, Smoney: string;
  meloen, pruim, citroen, banaan, zeven: TPicture;

implementation

{$R *.lfm}

{ TForm1 }

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
   s4:=label3.Caption;
  if s4='0' then label1.Caption:='Kies een inzet bedrag!'
  else
  begin
  Smoney:=label2.Caption;
  money:=StrToFloat(Smoney);

  x4:=StrToFloat(s4);
  if x4>money then label1.Caption:='Uw inzet is te hoog!'
  else
  begin
  money:=money-x4;
  Smoney:=FloatToStr(money);
  label2.Caption:=Smoney;
  image1.Picture.LoadFromFile('rol2.png');
  image2.Picture.LoadFromFile('rol2.png');
  image3.Picture.LoadFromFile('rol2.png');
  image4.Picture.LoadFromFile('rol1.png');
  image5.Picture.LoadFromFile('rol2.png');
  image6.Picture.LoadFromFile('rol3.png');
  image7.Picture.LoadFromFile('rol1.png');
  image8.Picture.LoadFromFile('rol2.png');
  image9.Picture.LoadFromFile('rol3.png');
  timer1.Enabled:=true;

  end;

  end;

end;

procedure TForm1.Button18Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  label1.Caption:='';
  label2.Caption:='100';
  label3.Caption:='0';
end;

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  label3.Caption:='1';
end;
procedure TForm1.Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  label3.Caption:='2';
end;
procedure TForm1.Button4Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  label3.Caption:='3';
end;
procedure TForm1.Button5Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  label3.Caption:='4';
end;
procedure TForm1.Button6Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  label3.Caption:='5';
end;
procedure TForm1.Button7Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  label3.Caption:='10';
end;
procedure TForm1.Button8Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  label3.Caption:='20';
end;
procedure TForm1.Button9Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  label3.Caption:='25';
end;
procedure TForm1.Button10Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  label3.Caption:='50';
end;
procedure TForm1.Button11Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  label3.Caption:='75';
end;
procedure TForm1.Button12Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  label3.Caption:='100';
end;
procedure TForm1.Button13Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  label3.Caption:='200';
end;
procedure TForm1.Button14Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  label3.Caption:='250';
end;
procedure TForm1.Button15Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  label3.Caption:='500';
end;
procedure TForm1.Button16Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  label3.Caption:='750';
end;
procedure TForm1.Button17Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  label3.Caption:='1000';
end;

procedure TForm1.Timer1StopTimer(Sender: TObject);
begin


end;

procedure TForm1.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  x1:=random(2);
  x2:=random(5);
  x3:=random(5);
  if x1=1 then begin
     image1.Picture.LoadFromFile('kers.png');
     image4.Picture.LoadFromFile('meloen.png');
     image7.Picture.LoadFromFile('zeven.png');
     end;
  if x1=2 then begin
     image1.Picture.LoadFromFile('meloen.png');
     image4.Picture.LoadFromFile('zeven.png');
     image7.Picture.LoadFromFile('citroen.png');
  end;
  if x1=3 then begin
     image1.Picture.LoadFromFile('zeven.png');
     image4.Picture.LoadFromFile('citroen.png');
     image7.Picture.LoadFromFile('banaan.png');
  end;
  if x1=4 then begin
     image1.Picture.LoadFromFile('citroen.png');
     image4.Picture.LoadFromFile('banaan.png');
     image7.Picture.LoadFromFile('pruim.png');
       end;
  if x1=5 then begin
     image1.Picture.LoadFromFile('banaan.png');
     image4.Picture.LoadFromFile('pruim.png');
     image7.Picture.LoadFromFile('big.png');
       end;
  if x1=6 then begin
     image1.Picture.LoadFromFile('pruim.png');
     image4.Picture.LoadFromFile('big.png');
     image7.Picture.LoadFromFile('bar.png');
       end;
  if x1=7 then begin
     image1.Picture.LoadFromFile('big.png');
     image4.Picture.LoadFromFile('bar.png');
     image7.Picture.LoadFromFile('sinaas.png');
       end;
  if x1=8 then begin
     image1.Picture.LoadFromFile('bar.png');
     image4.Picture.LoadFromFile('sinaas.png');
     image7.Picture.LoadFromFile('kers.png');
       end;
  if x1=9 then begin
     image1.Picture.LoadFromFile('sinaas.png');
     image4.Picture.LoadFromFile('kers.png');
     image7.Picture.LoadFromFile('meloen.png');
       end;



  if x2=1 then begin
     image2.Picture.LoadFromFile('kers.png');
     image5.Picture.LoadFromFile('meloen.png');
     image8.Picture.LoadFromFile('zeven.png');
       end;
  if x2=2 then begin
     image2.Picture.LoadFromFile('meloen.png');
     image5.Picture.LoadFromFile('zeven.png');
     image8.Picture.LoadFromFile('citroen.png');
       end;
  if x2=3 then begin
     image2.Picture.LoadFromFile('zeven.png');
     image5.Picture.LoadFromFile('citroen.png');
     image8.Picture.LoadFromFile('banaan.png');
       end;
  if x2=4 then begin
     image2.Picture.LoadFromFile('citroen.png');
     image5.Picture.LoadFromFile('banaan.png');
     image8.Picture.LoadFromFile('pruim.png');
       end;
  if x2=5 then begin
     image2.Picture.LoadFromFile('banaan.png');
     image5.Picture.LoadFromFile('pruim.png');
     image8.Picture.LoadFromFile('big.png');
       end;
  if x2=6 then begin
     image2.Picture.LoadFromFile('pruim.png');
     image5.Picture.LoadFromFile('big.png');
     image8.Picture.LoadFromFile('bar.png');
       end;
  if x2=7 then begin
     image2.Picture.LoadFromFile('big.png');
     image5.Picture.LoadFromFile('bar.png');
     image8.Picture.LoadFromFile('sinaas.png');
       end;
  if x2=8 then begin
     image2.Picture.LoadFromFile('bar.png');
     image5.Picture.LoadFromFile('sinaas.png');
     image8.Picture.LoadFromFile('kers.png');
       end;
  if x2=9 then begin
     image2.Picture.LoadFromFile('sinaas.png');
     image5.Picture.LoadFromFile('kers.png');
     image8.Picture.LoadFromFile('meloen.png');
       end;



  if x3=1 then begin
     image3.Picture.LoadFromFile('kers.png');
     image6.Picture.LoadFromFile('meloen.png');
     image9.Picture.LoadFromFile('zeven.png');
       end;
  if x3=2 then begin
     image3.Picture.LoadFromFile('meloen.png');
     image6.Picture.LoadFromFile('zeven.png');
     image9.Picture.LoadFromFile('citroen.png');
       end;
  if x3=3 then begin
     image3.Picture.LoadFromFile('zeven.png');
     image6.Picture.LoadFromFile('citroen.png');
     image9.Picture.LoadFromFile('banaan.png');
       end;
  if x3=4 then begin
     image3.Picture.LoadFromFile('citroen.png');
     image6.Picture.LoadFromFile('banaan.png');
     image9.Picture.LoadFromFile('pruim.png');
       end;
  if x3=5 then begin
     image3.Picture.LoadFromFile('banaan.png');
     image6.Picture.LoadFromFile('pruim.png');
     image9.Picture.LoadFromFile('big.png');
       end;
  if x3=6 then begin
     image3.Picture.LoadFromFile('pruim.png');
     image6.Picture.LoadFromFile('big.png');
     image9.Picture.LoadFromFile('bar.png');
       end;
  if x3=7 then begin
     image3.Picture.LoadFromFile('big.png');
     image6.Picture.LoadFromFile('bar.png');
     image9.Picture.LoadFromFile('sinaas.png');
       end;
  if x3=8 then begin
     image3.Picture.LoadFromFile('bar.png');
     image6.Picture.LoadFromFile('sinaas.png');
     image9.Picture.LoadFromFile('kers.png');
       end;
  if x3=9 then begin
     image3.Picture.LoadFromFile('sinaas.png');
     image6.Picture.LoadFromFile('kers.png');
     image9.Picture.LoadFromFile('meloen.png');
       end;




  if (x1=x2) and (x2=x3) then
     begin
     x4:=x4*10;
     money:=StrToFloat(Smoney);
     money:=money+x4;
     Smoney:=FloatToStr(money);
     label2.caption:=Smoney;
     x4:=x4/4;
     end
  else if (x1=x2) xor (x2=x3) xor (x1=x3) then
     begin
     x4:=x4*3;
     money:=StrToFloat(Smoney);
     money:=money+x4;
     Smoney:=FloatToStr(money);
     label2.caption:=Smoney;
     x4:=x4/2;
     end;
  timer1.Enabled:=false;

end;

procedure TForm1.Timer2Timer(Sender: TObject);
var
  i:integer;
  y:double;
begin
 image1.Picture.LoadFromFile('rol.png');

end;

end.
```

[code](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/anonymous/f44ad4206007872d6521/raw/5c194ca7327cf56143e248480c4b25476dddd799/slotmachine)

Comment: i've fixed it. just put the pictures behind each other. couldnt load the gif.. couldnt get a video in... no other way.. maybe with more pictures it looks better but its working now.
thx for al the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could load the 100x900 image into a TBitmap and then use the image's Canvas property and the CopyRect method of the canvas to draw from any rectangle in the bitmap to the canvas. For example, if your bitmap is loaded into FFruit and you use FPos for the line in the bitmap (e.g. the third picture would start at 200):

```
Image1.Canvas.CopyRect(Rect(0, 0, 100, 100), FFruit.Canvas, Rect(0, FPos, 100, FPos+100));
```

You can do this in your timer event and also update FPos in it.

One criticism of your current code that you posted: don't do the LoadFromFile method calls in the timer. Load the images once into TBitmaps and just assign them in the timer. LoadFromFile takes a lot of disk reading and processing.

Comment: this is what i was searching for!